# Excel Lookup on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two tables

[image]

And

[image]

The table structure remaining the same, how do I write a lookup statement on excel to get the output in Table 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No formula as you do not show cell references, but the conventional solution is to add a column concatenating `Date` and `Source` for the lower table and then apply a lookup function with a search term that combines `Date` and (separately) each of the other two labels in Table 1.